# How to get the revert data in ethers-rs?

Tags: rust, ethereum

Suppose I have a contract

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.13;

error Hello(string name);

contract Thrower {
    function sayHello() public {
        revert Hello("World");
    }
}
```

If I call `sayHello` using ethers-rs, how can I access the revert data to decode it?

I tried:

```rust
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let provider = Provider::<Http>::try_from("http://localhost:8545")?;
    let wallet: LocalWallet = PRIVATE_KEY.parse()?;
    let client = SignerMiddleware::new_with_provider_chain(provider, wallet).await?;
    let thrower = Thrower::deploy(Arc::new(client), ())?.send().await?;
    let error = thrower.say_hello().call().await.unwrap_err();
    println!("{error:#?}");
    Ok(())
}
```

The type of `error` is `ContractError<SignerMiddleware<Provider<Http>, LocalWallet>>`, and printing it gives

```
MiddlewareError(
    MiddlewareError(
        JsonRpcClientError(
            JsonRpcError(
                JsonRpcError {
                    code: 3,
                    message: "execution reverted",
                    data: Some(
                        String("0xe762c7c600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005576f726c64000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"),
                    ),
                },
            ),
        ),
    ),
)
```

I can see the data I want in there, and manually copying the hex-string out of the error does let me decode it:

```rust
    let name = Hello::decode_hex("0xe762c7c6000…00")?.name;
    assert_eq!(name, "World");
```

but I can't figure out how to access that data programmatically. I could destructure the error layer by layer, but there's a lot of layers and this feels fragile: it would break if my provider stack changed (e.g. changing HTTP to WS). Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **pattern matching** to match against this specific error and ignore the rest. Needless to say, ignoring errors is bad practice and it is strongly advised to handle all possible errors to avoid runtime failures.

**NOTE:** *The ethers-rs version used for this solution is 2.0.11 (the latest version at the time of writing this solution)*

First, include the types:

```rust
use serde_json::Value;
use ethers::{
    contract::ContractError,
    middleware::signer::SignerMiddlewareError,
    providers::{JsonRpcError, ProviderError}
};
```

Then, handle the specific error in question:

```
match err {
    ContractError::MiddlewareError {
        e: SignerMiddlewareError::MiddlewareError(ProviderError::JsonRpcClientError(err)),
    } => {
        if let Some(JsonRpcError {
            code: _,
            message: _,
            data: Some(Value::String(hex)),
        }) = err.as_error_response() // try to convert JsonRpcClientError into JsonRpcError
        {
            let name = Hello::decode_hex(hex)?.name;
            assert_eq!(name, "World");
        } else {
            println!("{err:?}");
        }
    }
    _ => (), // If you care about other errors, read the full solution below.
}
```

Also adding the code to handle all cases, you can of course improve readability by defining error handler functions instead of handling them inline, please replace the todo macro with the appropriate handling of errors:

```rust
match err {
    ContractError::MiddlewareError { e } => match e {
        SignerMiddlewareError::MiddlewareError(provider_error) => match provider_error {
            ProviderError::JsonRpcClientError(err) => {
                if let Some(JsonRpcError {
                    code: _,
                    message: _,
                    data: Some(Value::String(hex)),
                }) = err.as_error_response() // try to convert JsonRpcClientError into JsonRpcError
                {
                    let name = Hello::decode_hex(hex)?.name;
                    assert_eq!(name, "World");
                } else {
                    println!("{err:?}");
                }
            }
            ProviderError::EnsError(_) => todo!(),
            ProviderError::EnsNotOwned(_) => todo!(),
            ProviderError::SerdeJson(_) => todo!(),
            ProviderError::HexError(_) => todo!(),
            ProviderError::HTTPError(_) => todo!(),
            ProviderError::CustomError(_) => todo!(),
            ProviderError::UnsupportedRPC => todo!(),
            ProviderError::UnsupportedNodeClient => todo!(),
            ProviderError::SignerUnavailable => todo!(),
        },
        SignerMiddlewareError::SignerError(_) => todo!(),
        SignerMiddlewareError::NonceMissing => todo!(),
        SignerMiddlewareError::GasPriceMissing => todo!(),
        SignerMiddlewareError::GasMissing => todo!(),
        SignerMiddlewareError::WrongSigner => todo!(),
        SignerMiddlewareError::DifferentChainID => todo!(),
    },
    ContractError::DecodingError(_) => todo!(),
    ContractError::AbiError(_) => todo!(),
    ContractError::DetokenizationError(_) => todo!(),
    ContractError::ProviderError { e: _ } => todo!(),
    ContractError::Revert(_) => todo!(),
    ContractError::ConstructorError => todo!(),
    ContractError::ContractNotDeployed => todo!(),
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Accessing the EVM revert data is the same regardless of the programming language.

It is done by replaying the transaction using `eth_call` JSON-RPC endpoint. Then in the call results, you can extract the revert reason.

[You can find a revert reason Python implementation here](https://web3-ethereum-defi.readthedocs.io/api/_autosummary/eth_defi.revert_reason.fetch_transaction_revert_reason.html#eth_defi.revert_reason.fetch_transaction_revert_reason) of which should source code should be easy to translate to Rust.